# Angular allows for overscrolling on mobile, leaving white bar

Tags: angular, angular-material

I noticed that on mobile phones, if you scroll to the bottom of my Angular page (which uses Angular Material and some Bootstrap elements), you are sometimes able to "overscroll" for a lack of better words. This results in the background of the browser itself being shown - in Chrome mobile this would be a white bar, for Firefox mobile with dark mode enabled it would be a black bar.

[image: white bar on mobile phone]

Interestingly enough, this does **not** happen when I try to replicate it using the developer mode of Chrome or Firefox on my PC, leading me to believe that it has something to do with the way mobile browsers handle my page. Here is a video of my trying to replicate it on my PC.

[image: no white bar on desktop pc]

As far as I am aware, this issue appears on all my pages. Just for the sake of completeness, here is the source code of the page `entry.component.html`:

```
<div class="container p-3">

  <!-- Logo -->
  <div class="row pt-3">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <img alt="logo" class="mb-3 mt-2" src="assets/image/logo.svg"
           style="max-width: 25vw; max-height: 25vh"
           (click)="changeMode()"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Description -->
  <mat-card class="mt-3 mx-3">
    <mat-card-header class="pp-center">
      <mat-card-title i18n>
        Title
      </mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content class="text-center">
      <!--      <p>{{"module.entry.welcome" | translate}}</p>-->
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur metus tellus</p>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur metus tellus</p>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>

  <!-- Authentication -->
  <mat-card class="mt-3 mx-3">
    <mat-card-header class="pp-center">
      <mat-card-title>
        {{"module.authentication.title" | translate}}
      </mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content class="text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <app-signup></app-signup>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row mt-1">
        <div class="col">
          <app-signin></app-signin>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>

  <!-- Credits -->
  <mat-card class="mt-3 mx-3">
    <mat-card-content class="text-center">
      <p>{{"module.version.version" | translate}} 1.0</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p><i>Text</i></p>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>

</div>
```

Furthermore, in order to correctly show the material background I needed to do this for my `app.component.html`:

```
<body [ngClass]="darkTheme ? 'dark-theme' : ''" class="mat-typography mat-app-background">
<div class="mat-app-background">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
</body>
```

As I have no clue what could cause this, I would really appreciate any pointers on how to solve this issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What finally solved the problem (after a lot of trial and error) was replacing the following CSS

```
body {
  height: 100;
}
```

by

```
.app-root {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```